# Python binding with Strings that include escape characters

Tags: python, mysql, sql

My code is the following:

```
select_query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in (%s)"
parameters = "'"+"','".join(['\\','--','where'])+"'"
cursor.execute(select_query, parameters)
print str(cursor._executed)
```

The query I want executed is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('\','--','where')
```

I got to this parameters as last resort - it still doesn't do exactly what I want. Python escape the characters, the print returns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('\'\\\',\'--\',\'where\'')
```

Comment: does this fail? or do you want to see a "pretty" print?

Comment: I guess that this only looks like that, because in an interactive session, just typing 'abc' will `print(repr('abc'))`.

Comment: I didn't understand what you've said... I wasn't working in interactive mode. I have a query with binding that is not formatted as I want it to (As shown above) + I show the cursor._executed to demonstrate how it is formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `parameters` is a string which contains characters which `MySQLdb` will attempt to escape.

You can just interpolate the query string yourself...

```
select_query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in (%s)"
parameters = "'"+"','".join(['\\','--','where'])+"'"
cursor.execute(select_query % parameters)
print str(cursor._executed)
```

...but that's vulnerable to SQL injection, and won't work in your case, since it'll produce...

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('\','--','where')
```

...which isn't a valid query, as you can see from SO's syntax highlighting.

It's safer to do something like this...

```
parameters = ['\\','--','where']
placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(parameters))
select_query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in (%s)" % placeholders
cursor.execute(select_query, parameters)
print str(cursor._executed)
```

...which will produce a query like...

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('\\','--','where')
```

...which I assume is what you really want.

---

**Update**

> I was hoping not to do something like: placeholders = ','.join(['%s']
>   * len(parameters)) This is why I posted here - isn't there a better solution?

Well, I'm not sure this is any "better", but you can use the `MySQLdb`-specific `Connection.escape_string()` method, or the underlying [`_mysql`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysql) module's `escape_string()` function...

```
>>> import _mysql
>>> select_query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in (%s)"
>>> parameters = "'"+"','".join(map(_mysql.escape_string, ['\\','--','where']))+"'"
>>> print select_query % parameters
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('\\','--','where')
```

...but `Connection.escape_string()` isn't mentioned in [PEP249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), so you'll lose cross-DB compatibility.

Comment: I was hoping not to do something like:
placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(parameters))

This is why I posted here - isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just enter it as a raw string?

put an `r` in front of the string;

`print "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('\','--','where')"`

`SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('','--','where')`

whereas with the `r`:

`print r"SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('\','--','where')"`

`SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE name in ('\','--','where')`